# Running Groovy scripts in Pipeline on Slaves

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently attempting to run Groovy code using Jenkins Pipeline, but I'm finding that my scripts run the Groovy part of the code on the Master rather than the Slaves despite me noting the agent.

I have a Repo in Git named JenkinsFiles containing the below JenkinsFile, as well as a repo named CommonLibrary, which contains the code run in the Stages.

Here's my JenkinsFile :

```
@Library(['CommonLibrary']) _

pipeline {
    agent { label 'Slave' }
    stages {
        stage("Preparation") {
            agent { label 'Slave && Windows' }
            steps {
                Preparation()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Preparation.groovy file :

```
def call() {
    println("Running on : " + InetAddress.localHost.canonicalHostName)
}
```

Unfortunately, I always seem to get the Master returned when I run the Pipeline in Jenkins. I've tried manually installing Groovy on the Slave, and have also removed the Executors on the Master. Any Powershell that gets run triggers correctly on the Slave, and the $NODE_NAME value returns as the Slave, but it's just the Groovy commands that seem to run on the Master.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! - Tor

Comment: How is the method invocation executing if it is outside of a `script` block?

Comment: Not sure, I suspect Groovy is doing something in the background that I'm not aware of. I get the same result if I wrap it in a script block

Comment: Groovy scripts always run on the master, using a so-called flyweight executor. See https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012808951-Pipeline-Difference-between-flyweight-and-heavyweight-Executors You have to use pipeline steps or run a shell script if you want something to run in the node's context.